# add attribute to checkbox "checked " with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not much familiar with javascript or jQuery. I want to actually add and remove the `checked` **attribute** on a checkbox when its value changes, so that the attribute is included if we get the HTML of the checkbox (we store this HTML and want the state to be stored). Here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).on('click','.mark-as-done',function()
{
    if($(this).prop("checked"))
    {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
    $(this).attr('checked','checked');
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="task" class="mark-as-done" style=" float: left;margin-top: 13px;">
```

Comment: But...why? Don't checkboxes work like that automatically? In any case, have you tried adding an `else` block? (And why are you mixing `.attr()` and `.prop()`? Why not just `this.checked`?)

Comment: i want to save the html in the db . and have to show checked

Comment: @ris What you want to store to DB?

Comment: the chackboxes ..<input type="checkbox" " class="mark-as-done" name="task" checked="">

Comment: @ris: That was **really** important information to include in the question.

Comment: but which value you what to pass? You have not used `value=" "`

Comment: @ris please explain proper so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has special handling around the attributes with reflected properties (like `checked`), so you need to go straight to the DOM to do this. Also, your logic was **always** adding the attribute (because you didn't use `else` or `return` when removing it).

But it's just as easy with the DOM:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".mark-as-done", function() {
  // Actually add/remove the attribute, so that it's in the serialized
  // form when we store it (the `value` *property* isn't included when
  // serializing, so we do the attribute)
  if (this.checked) {
    this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
  } else {
    this.removeAttribute("checked");
  }
  snippet.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="mark-as-done">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and IE11.